# Jquery mobile navigation functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to implement a jquery mobile navigation. But build my own from the jquery load()
function. I have looked at history.js but its so hard to understand. It would be great to see the correct url for the page in the adressbar. Please can someone help pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple History.js example.

Our markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.history.js"></script>
<title>History.js</title>
</head>
<body>

        <a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
        <a href="Page2.html">Page 2</a>
     <div id="content">
        <p>Content within this box is replaced with content from
            supporting pages using javascript and AJAX.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript.

```
$(function() {

            // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower 'h'
            var History = window.History; 
            if (!History.enabled) {
                // History.js is disabled for this browser.
                // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
                return false;
            }

            // Bind to StateChange Event
            History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(e) {
                // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
                var State = History.getState();
                $('#content').load(State.url + " #content").html();
            });

            $('a').on('click',function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                History.pushState(null, $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));
            });
        });
```

Insert that script either in the head tag or bottom of the page. basically pages1.html and page2.html should contain a div called content, and it would return you the contents using the method load from `$('#content').load(State.url + " #content").html();`

and that's about it.

Comment: I have found ajaxify-html5.js also and it looks good, how can I use it?

Comment: Seems to work great, but the content container on my startpage when going backwards goes empty. Isnt initialy.

Comment: Still have some problems to load the initial data from startpage when I go all the way to start history. Why is that, need to load tha inital data for the first history record?